# Прописные буквы в названии памятника

Tags: орфография, прописная-строчная

В Севастополе есть памятник, в народе называемый "человек-паук", но официальное его название "памятник матросу и солдату". Так вот, как правильно его написать, должны ли тут быть какие-то прописные буквы, например, "памятник Матросу и Солдату"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще в таких случаях определяющим является официальное название.
Но я бы согласился с использованием заглавных, здесь слова используются в особом, возвышеном значении.